# Qlikview selections from an extension

Tags: qlikview

I am writing an extension for qlikview and I want to change the qlikview current selection from the extension script, is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can feed back selections to the parent document. Depending on how your extension is created and the data that feeds it, you can use the `SearchColumn`, `SelectValuesInColumn` or `SelectTextsInColumn` API methods.

Taking the below code from one of my other answers, say we have our `Data` set up as follows:

```
for (var rowIx = 0; rowIx < this.Data.Rows.length; rowIx++) {
   var row = this.Data.Rows[rowIx];
   myDimensionValue = row[0].text;
   myMeasureValue = row[1].text;
}
```

You can then use the `SelectTextsInColumn` method as follows:

```
this.Data.SelectTextsInColumn(column, toggle, recordsToSelect);
```

Where:

- *column* (integer): the column number to filter
- *toggle* (boolean): if true, existing selections will be kept
- *recordsToSelect*: Can either be an array or a simple list of parameters.

For the above example:

```
this.Data.SearchColumn(0, true, "My Selected Value", "My Second Selected Value");
```

More information on these methods can be found in the JS SDK available from QlikTech.